# BigQuery / Node.js timestamp way off

Tags: node.js, timestamp, google-bigquery

Doing a streaming insert into Google BigQuery, from a light Node.js app, using this package: https://www.npmjs.org/package/bigquery

I generated a timestamp on my server via this simple line of code:

```
jsonData['createdAt'] = new Date().getTime();
```

I then insert that into BigQuery, into a field with type 'timestamp'.  There is no intermediate step (besides the Node package).

But many, although not all, of dates look waaaaaay off.  For example:

```
46343-08-28 05:58:59 UTC
```

When that should say something like 11:45pm on 05-16-2014.  However, some of my createdAt dates are correct, and I can't find a reason for the difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without actually debugging the JS code, this seems to be an "off by a thousand" problem.

Check this out:

```
SELECT USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1400341611711851)
2014-05-17 15:46:51 UTC

SELECT USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1400341611711851*1000)
46345-01-22 13:01:51 UTC

SELECT MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1400341611711851)
46345-01-22 13:01:51 UTC

SELECT MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1400341611711851/1000)
2014-05-17 15:46:51 UTC
```

So to get a UNIX timestamp in seconds, divide the `new Date().getTime()` number by 1000.

Comment: Seems to be the issue.  Thanks much.

Comment: To add to this answer, javascript Date "getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch."
And Timestamp uses the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

bigquery.datetime(new Date().toISOString())

Comment: Please edit your answer with more detail: How does this solve the OP's problem? How is it useful when compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: When Googling for a solution to this issue, this suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had a requirement where I am supposed to send Timestamp type to BigQuery table from NodeJS.
I did it as follows:

```
bigqueryClient.timestamp(new Date(Date.now()))
```

I hope this may help someone.